# How to compare current time with 26/09/2018 04:10 AM

Tags: mysql, sql

how to compare time with current time but with AM pm format also compare in mysql select query.
I added Database image where stored time in this formate and i compare to current time but i didn't get success.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `expectedDeliveryDateTime` to a date so you can compare it with `NOW()`. To do that you need to use [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) with the format `'%d/%m/%Y %h:%i %p'` which matches the data in your image. So try:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(expectedDeliveryDateTime, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i %p') >= NOW()
```

I have assumed you are looking for dates in the future, if you want dates in the past just change `>= NOW()` to `<= NOW()`.

Answer (score 1):

use `now()`and format date using `date_format`as your column is varchar so you have to convert it date by using `STR_TO_DATE` function

```
  select * from t where
STR_TO_DATE(expectedDeliveryDateTime, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i %p')  >=date_format(now(), '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i %p')
```

Comment: But it's not compare with expectedDeliveryDateTime field.

Comment: Yes you are right but it's not compare time with AM PM it's show today date 26/09/2018 04:10 AM this one not want in result.

Comment: Datatype is Varchar

Comment: convert it on date

Comment: 26/09/2018 04:10 AM this format not work on Date datatype

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180788/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-vivek-manavadariya).

Answer (score 0):

Please, check my time zone. Are we the same?

`SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP() from dual;`

If the same, then you compare is correct.